# Selecionar cidades com o SharedPreference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Apenas quando clico em "Itaborai" que salva o preference, como faço pra quando selecionar os outros itens da list view entre em outras activitys?
Como exemplo, o cliente clicou em "Itaborai" quando ele abrir o app de novo vai abrir direto a classe Itaborai. Quero colocar a função do "Itaborai" nos outros itens do listview pra abrir novas classes.

```
 public class Selecionar_Cid extends ActionBarActivity {


ListView lista;

String[] config = new String[]{
        "Itaborai",
        "Cachoeiras",
        "Manilha",


};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_selecionar);


    // Verfificar se a classe já foi selecionada
    int city = Integer.parseInt(Pref.retrievePrefKeyValue(getApplicationContext(), "city", "-1"));
    if (city != -1) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Selecionar_Cid.this, Verificar_Internet_Itaborai.class);
        startActivity(i);



    }


    lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    ArrayAdapter adaptador = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, config);

    lista.setAdapter(adaptador);
    lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int posicion, long l) {
            Pref.savePrefKeyValue(getApplicationContext(), "city", String.valueOf(posicion));


            // TODO colocar o clique nas outras cidades

            switch (posicion) {


                case 0:
                    Intent i = new Intent(Selecionar_Cid.this, Verificar_Internet_Itaborai.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    break;

                default:

            }
        }
    });
}


}
```

Preference

```
public class Pref {


public static void savePrefKeyValue( Context context, String key, String value ){
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor e = sp.edit();
    e.putString( key, value );
    e.apply();
}
public static String retrievePrefKeyValue( Context context, String key, String... defaultValue ){
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences( context );
    String dValue = defaultValue != null && defaultValue.length > 0 ? defaultValue[0] : "";
    sp.getString(key, dValue );
    return( sp.getString( key, dValue ) );
}
```

}